# Is it possible to have 2 different CGridView in one admin.php in Yii?

Tags: yii, cgridview

Is it possible to have 2 different CGridView Tables in one admin.php ?

For example, I have a page of Services and a page of Packages.

Services are basically individual single services whereas Packages consist of individual services.

So, my question is, can I have the Service's CGridView to be displayed in Package/admin.php page? A seperate CGridView table.

Top part with list of Packages, and at the bottom, a different table, with Individual services.

If so, please guide me through it. Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

```
public function actionAdmin() {
    $model = new Package('search');
    $model2 = new Service('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    $model2->unsetAttributes();
    $model->active=1;
    $model2->active=1;

    if (isset($_GET['Package'])){
        $model->setAttributes($_GET['Package']);
    }

    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'model2' => $model2,
    ));
}
```

Under _form.php:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'service-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model2->search(),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view grid-size'),
    'filter' => $model2,
    'columns' => array( //the appropriate columns
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and you can have any number of grid views in one page/action.

here is a example where i display two gridviews, namely Manage Subjects 1 & Manage Subjects 2

```
<?php
/* @var $this SubjectController */
/* @var $model Subject */
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    Yii::t('edu', 'Subjects') => array('index'),
    Yii::t('edu', 'Manage'),
);
?>
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('application.views.layouts._actions', array('model' => $model)); ?>
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $('.search-button').click(function(){
        $('.search-form').toggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('.search-form form').submit(function(){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('data-grid', {
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
        return false;
    });
");
?>
<h3><?php echo Yii::t('edu', 'Manage Subjects 1'); ?></h3>
<!-- search-form -->
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
    <p>You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b> or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.</p>
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_search', array('model' => $model)); ?>
</div>
<!-- search-form -->
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_grid', array('model' => $model)); ?>

    <h3><?php echo Yii::t('edu', 'Manage Subjects 2'); ?></h3>
    <!-- search-form -->
    <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
        <p>You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b> or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.</p>
        <?php $this->renderPartial('_search', array('model' => $model)); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- search-form -->
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_grid', array('model' => $model)); ?>
```

**Update**

you need to create 2 models, see my below code, model2 is created and its a different table. you pass it to admin.php and in the gridview change model to model2 in your second gridview. thats all.

```
/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model = new Subject('search');
    $model2 = new Institute('search');
    Yii::app()->appLog->writeLog('Manage Subjects.');  // Activity log entry
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // Clear any default values

    $data = TK::get('Subject');
    if ($data !== null)
        $model->attributes = $data;

    $params = array('model' => $model, 'model2' => $model2);
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        $this->renderPartial('_grid', $params);
    else
        $this->render('admin', $params);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. But isn't what you're doing is coming from the same table but just in separated table? I want 2 different tables to be in the same page in a separated table. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, so now I have successfully integrated 2 tables into 1 admin page. But for the search, it's not working for the 2nd table. The search in original table is perfectly fine but not in the 2nd table. Can I know what I can add in order for it to work properly? Thanks

Comment: @Yeen i hope u posted the _grid.php file, kindly make two files and try as _grid.php & _grid2.php and use for both models. if it dont work, please create another question in stack overflow,

Comment: I don't have any file called "_grid.php". Where can I get it from?